# Is it possible to check if a key of a class is of certain custom type

Tags: typescript

I have the following code and I would like to create a new mapped type from `Test`, which contains only the keys that are of `Custom` type.

The custom properties don't have anything special behind them besides the annotation. When I paste this in TS playground, the `CustomKeys` type contains both keys, however, if I modify the check when mapping the keys to `... extends Custom<string>`, it works properly.

Is there a way to accomplish this in which an explicit type is not provided to the check?

```js
type Custom<T extends any = unknown> = T;

class Test {
  customProperty!: Custom<string>;
  notCustomProperty!: number;
}

type PickCustomKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Custom ? K : never]: T[K];
};

type CustomKeys = PickCustomKeys<Test>
```

Comment: The implementation where `Custom` is just defined as `Custom<T> = T` makes this impossible. Every type extends `Custom` based on this definition. You can't detect a difference between `number` and `Custom<number>`, because there is none.

Comment: I see, I was playing around with ChatGPT and it was telling me that it was possible all along haha, so I thought it almost got it, but not quite. Well, in my scenario, I think I can count on them extending `object`, so I will include that type in the check. Thanks a lot